# Как сделать пароль

Tags: java, android

Я новичок в программировании. Расскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать что-то вроде пароля.

Пользователь должен ввести определенное слово и активити будет выполняться дальше. Не могу разобраться, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: В определённый момент отобразите незакрываемый (cancalabe=false) диалог.

Comment: Я не понимаю как программно задать строку и если она не соответствует определенному значению, то выводится что-то типа "попробуйте ещё раз". Желательно не используя диалог.

Comment: Ввести строку может только юзер. Значит нужно поле ввода и клава. А блокировать активити можно диалогом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**res/values/strings.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyAndroidApp</string>
    <string name="lblPassword">Enter Your Password :</string>
    <string name="btn_submit">Submit</string>
</resources>
```

**res/layout/main.xml**:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lblPassword"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_submit" />
```

**Код**:

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {
  private EditText password;
  private Button btnSubmit;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addListenerOnButton();
  }

  public void addListenerOnButton() {
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);   
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this, password.getText(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

[Источник](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-password-field-example/).

---

[**Вот урок**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_login_screen.htm) создания окошка с входом в момент открытия приложения.

А вообще, просто воспользуйтесь Гуглом - там [**масса примеров**](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=java%20android%20password%20activity).